# Run docker commands within pod using helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to run a docker container within a job that I am deploying with helm using AKS. The purpose of this is to run some tests using Selenium and make some postgres calls to automate web ui tests.

When trying to run within the job, the following error is received:
"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

I ran into this problem locally, but can work around it using
`docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock web-ui-auto:latest /bin/bash`

The problem is I am using helm to deploy the job separate from the running tasks since it can take about an hour to complete.

I tried adding a deployment.yaml to my helm like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "web-ui-auto.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "web-ui-auto.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "web-ui-auto.chart" . }}
    draft: {{ .Values.draft | default "draft-app" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "web-ui-auto.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "web-ui-auto.name" . }}
        draft: {{ .Values.draft | default "draft-app" }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
      annotations:
        buildID: {{ .Values.buildID | default "" | quote }}
        container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/{{ .Chart.Name }}: runtime/default
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsNonRoot }}
            runAsUser: {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsUser }}
            runAsGroup: {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsGroup }}
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: {{ .Values.securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation }}
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.deployment.containerPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: dockersock
              mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
      volumes:
        - name: dockersock
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

but was met with failures still. My question is what is the best method to run docker within the job successfully when deploying with helm. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't really run `docker` commands in a Kubernetes environment at all: the cluster isn't guaranteed to be running Docker proper, and since you can use Docker to root the node it's running on, it's unlikely the Docker socket would be accessible to a pod.  Can you restructure your setup to not need to dynamically launch containers?

Comment: Why not have a `test` container image (with Selenium+else inside) and supply configuration with a ConfigMap? The container's execution will perform the test.

Comment: I did more research, and I guess aks prevents you from using their docker.sock and mounting it. We kind of wanted to avoid making our services image larger than it was already including postgres to do some other calls that is only used for this pipeline, but it appears to be a limitation.